# python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully (python 3.10)

Tags: python, pip, apple-m1

i'm new to data science and i need to install scikit-surprise on my M1 chip using python 3.10. But i get this error instead. Somehow i get this message often with python 3.10.

i only install with pip

`%pip install scikit-surprise`

and i get this error. what should i do?

`python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully (python 3.10)`

[image: error]

````
  Building wheel for scikit-surprise (setup.py) ... error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [101 lines of output]
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:717: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/surprise
      copying surprise/builtin_datasets.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/surprise
      copying surprise/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/surprise
      copying surprise/dump.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/surprise
...

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
pip install wheel
```

before running `pip install scikit-surprise`

Comment: i already installed it

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip install attrdict3
```

it worked for me